# How to use User Model defined in models.py for Authetication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

## What I want to do

1.Introducing authentication in `Django Rest Framework`

2.Doing authentication using **`User` model** I defined in as `models.Model`, not `admin-user` provided by `django` by default.

## Version

`django` : 3.1

`djangorestframework`:3.11.1

`python` : 3.7.6

## Situation

I am trying to creating an app that each user can exchange their items. I use `Django` in server side, and `React` in client side.

In order to introduce authentication and registration, I created `User` model in `models.py`. However, when I try to introducing these features in `Django Rest Framework` I notice that I may not be able to do that using `User` I define, perhaps I have to use `admin-user` `django` provides.

## Question

#### __ First of all, can I introduce authentication and registration features using `User` model I define myself ?__

I found I can edit `admin-user` itself so I edited it. It doesn't work.
Honestly, I don't understand whether I can introduce these features using `User` model as well.

I would like to teach me how to figure it out. And I would like to those who have combined `Django` and `React` to teach me some way to realize authentication and registration.

Thank you very much.

This is my `User` model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    profile = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    background = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    login = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # createdAt, updatedAt は時系列順等に並べたいモデルに付与
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

And custom admin-user.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("ユーザーネームは必ず必要です。")
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        return self.create_user(username, password)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    profile = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    background = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    login = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # createdAt, updatedAt は時系列順等に並べたいモデルに付与
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to make `django` use your custom user model instead of the built-in user model, you can tell `django` what to use.

So, in your `settings.py` file add this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.modelname'
```

Ex:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

As a reference: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

Then for custom authentication, go along with DRF docs, it's simple to write your custom authentication if you have a diffrent logic: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

For registration I recommend using `dj-rest-auth`: https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out by following your advice!